# How to compare two LinearGradients? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, linear-gradients

I have multiple gradients as themes for my app. I want to have a bool that becomes true when the gradient (stored in a variable) is a specific one. However, I keep getting an error:

> "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'LinearGradient'
>   operands"

Please HELP!

This is my code:

```
let pinkGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:[Color(red: 123/255, green: 30/255, blue: 122/255), Color(red: 248/255, green: 74/255, blue: 167/255)]), startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing)  
let blueGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:[Color(red: 0/255, green: 52/255, blue: 89/255), Color(red: 0/255, green: 168/255, blue: 232/255)]), startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing)  
let yellowGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:[Color(red: 240/255, green: 30/255, blue: 50/255), Color(red: 255/255, green: 189/255, blue: 0/255)]), startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing)  


if userData.selectedTheme == pinkGradient { //This is where the error occurs  
     self.isPinkThemeSelected = true  
} else if userData.selectedTheme == blueGradient { //This is where the error occurs  
     self.isBlueThemeSelected = true  
} else {  
     self.isYellowThemeSelected = true  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. Most SwiftUI views are "write-only." Once you've created them, you can't ask how they were created. (Path is a notable exception to this rule.)

Instead, I would recommend isolating your state from the gradient view itself. For example, you can create a `Theme` struct such as:

```
struct Theme: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // This ensures that even two themes with the same name are unique
    let name: String // This is just for your convenience
    let gradient: LinearGradient
}

extension Theme: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Theme, rhs: Theme) -> Bool { lhs.id == rhs.id }
}

let pinkTheme = Theme(name: "pink",
                      gradient: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:[
                        Color(red: 123/255, green: 30/255, blue: 122/255),
                        Color(red: 248/255, green: 74/255, blue: 167/255)]),
                                               startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing))

let blueTheme = Theme(name: "blue",
                      gradient: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:[
                        Color(red: 0/255, green: 52/255, blue: 89/255),
                        Color(red: 0/255, green: 168/255, blue: 232/255)]),
                                               startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing))
```

Now you can track `selectedThem == pinkTheme`.

If you have a fixed number of themes, you could also implement this more simply as an enum:

```
enum Theme: Equatable {
    case pink
    case blue
    case yellow

    var gradient: LinearGradient {
        switch self {
        case .pink: return LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:[
            Color(red: 123/255, green: 30/255, blue: 122/255),
            Color(red: 248/255, green: 74/255, blue: 167/255)]),
                                          startPoint: .bottomLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing)
        case .blue: ...
        case .yellow: ...
        }
    }
}
```